# SPARQL path traversing

Tags: sparql

I am trying to create a query using SPARQL on a ttl file where I have part of the graph representing links as follows: [image: links of a parent]

Is it possible to search for the type Debit and get all the literals associated with its parent ie: R494Vol1D2, Salvo, Vassallo?

Do I need to use paths?

Comment: Better if you show us the turtle, than this illustration. What SPARQL have you tried? What SPARQL processor, and what triple store, are you using?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: if you have the graph, 1) check which subgraph(s) you need 2) replace nodes/edges that you're interested in by variables and 3) translate each edge into a triple pattern.

Comment: but to answer your questions, yes it's possible and no, you don't need paths - at least not property paths. some triple patterns should be enough

Comment: by the way, it should be a **directed** graph, the direction matters in RDF and SPARQL

Comment: You *may* need Property Paths; among other things, this depends on how accurately the image above depicts the extent of the graph in your Turtle file, and whether that graph may change over time while you want to run the same query.... Incomplete details in your question mean we can only provide incomplete answers.

Answer (score 0):

As AKSW correctly said, RDF is about directed graphs. So I created a small n-triples file based on your image of the graph. I assume that the dataset looks like this:

```
<http://natarchives.com.mt/deed/R494Vol1-D2> <http://purl.org/dc/terms/type> "Debit".
<http://natarchives.com.mt/deed/R494Vol1-D2> <http://purl.org/dc/terms/identifier> "R494Vol1D2".
<http://natarchives.com.mt/deed/R494Vol1-D2> <http://data.archiveshub.ac.uk/def/associatedWith> <http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person796>.
<http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person796> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/firstName> "Salvo".
<http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person796> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/family_name> "Vassallo".
```

Also I did not know the prefix `locah` but according to http://prefix.cc it stands for http://data.archiveshub.ac.uk/def/

So if this dataset is correct you could use the following query:

```
1    SELECT ?literal WHERE{
2      ?start <http://purl.org/dc/terms/type> "Debit".
3      ?start <http://data.archiveshub.ac.uk/def/associatedWith>* ?parent.
4      ?parent ?hasLiteral ?literal.
5      FILTER(isLiteral(?literal) && ?literal != "Debit" )
6    }
```

In line 2 we define the starting point of our path, which is every vertex that has the type "Debit". Then we look for all vertices that are connected to ?start with an edge labelled with `<http://data.archiveshub.ac.uk/def/associatedWith>`. These vertices are then bound to `?parent`.  After that we look for all triples that have `?parent` as subject and store the object in `?literal`. In Line 6 we filter everything that is not a literal or is "Debit" from `?literal` resulting in the desired outcome.

If I modeled the direction of `<http://data.archiveshub.ac.uk/def/associatedWith>` wrongly, you could change line 3 of the query to:

```
?start ^<http://data.archiveshub.ac.uk/def/associatedWith>* ?parent
```

This would change the direction of the edge.

And to answer the question if you need to use paths: If you do not know how long the path of edges labeled with `<http://data.archiveshub.ac.uk/def/associatedWith>` will be, then in my opinion yes, you will have to use either * or + of property paths.